# Lower Semi-Continuous Functions Arising from Plane Flows

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, plane-geometry, semicontinuous-functions

If $X$ is a Hausdorff space, by a flow I mean a continuous surjection $F: X \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$ such that $F(x, s + t) = F(F(x,s), t)$ for all $x \in X$ and $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$.  If $x$ is periodic (or fixed) under $F$, then let $p_F(x)$ denote the minimal non-negative time such that $F(x, p_F(x)) = x$.  Otherwise, write $p_F(x) = \infty$.

In other words, $p_F(x)$ is the length of the period of $x$, and is infinite when $x$ is not periodic.

Then by a continuity argument you can show that the function $p_F(x)$ is lower semi-continuous from $X$ into $[0, \infty]$; especially, if $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $ 0 < p_F(x) = r < \infty$, then every finite accumulation point of $\lbrace p_F(x_n) \rbrace$ is a positive integer multiple of $r$, as necessary due to the continuity of F.

> What lsc functions $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ arise as $p_F$ for some plane flow $F$?

It's not all of them: For example, if $f$ is constantly $1$ except at a single point, where it takes the value $\frac{1}{2}$.  By the above argument, any jump discontinuity must be an integer multiple of the lower limit value, but the previous example shows that this is not sufficient.  Note that in the plane any non-periodic orbit of a flow is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, providing another 'obvious' constraint.

What are some other properties that might be sufficient to allow an associated flow?

Comment: The concept of a flow usually has $F(x, 0) = x$ for all $x$ as well (thus it identifies the partticles flowing by their position at time $0$). With that addendum, you'll also need to make a small adjustment to the definition of $p_F(x)$ to keep it from always being $0$.

Comment: That $F(x,0) = x$ is implied from the definition of flow, it doesn't need to be specified.  There's no need to make adjustments to the definition.  If $F$ is the constant flow then that's fine, $f \equiv 0$ is lsc.

Comment: Just to be clear, in your question what was $X$ has become $\mathbb{R}^2$, right?

Comment: Yeah, $X$ is the plane.  I couldn't decide if it was better to just state the definitions for the plane and have them seem very phenomenal, or state them generally.  Maybe it was the wrong call on this one xD

Comment: If $x\in X$ and $F(x,t)=x$ for each $t\in\mathbb R$ then $p_F(x)=0$, right?

Comment: In an answer, I drafted some steps to demonstrate that $p_F$, when it takes finite values, is continuous between those values. Are there known counterexamples ?

Answer (score 1):

Some preliminary observations, which can be helpful, but are too long for a comment.

Define a relation $\sim$ on $X$ putting $x\sim y$ if there exist $s,t\in\mathbb R$ such that $F(x,s)=F(y,t)$. It is easy to check that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, so $X$ splits into equivalence classes of $\sim$. Moreover, for each such class $C$ and each $x\in C$ we have $C=F(x,\mathbb R)$. It suggests to call equivalence classes of the relation $\sim$ *orbits*. It is easy to check that $p_F$ is constant on each orbit (as I understood, if $x\in X$ and $F(x,t)=x$ for each $t\in\mathbb R$ then $p_F(x)=0$, so we assume this). We have a partition $X=\bigcup_{T\in [0,\infty]} X_T$, where $X_T=\{x\in X:p_F(x)=T\}$ for each $T\in [0,\infty]$, and each $X_T$ is a disjoint union of orbits.

Not fix any finite $T$. If $T>0$ then each orbit $C$ constituting $X_T$ is homeomorphic to a circle. Moreover, put $\widetilde{X}_T=\{x\in X: F(x,T)=x\}$. By the continuity of $F$, $\widetilde X_T$ is closed. But $\widetilde{X}_T=X_0\cup\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} X_{T/n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but some hopefully useful remarks, supported by hand-waving arguments.

We would like to show that when $p_F < \infty$ in a zone, it is continuous.
Suppose $p_F$ is discontinuous. Then $\exists x, p_F(x)=T$, and $\exists (x_n), x_n \to x$ and $p_F(x_n) \not \to T$. We also suppose $\forall n, p_F(x_n) < \infty$.

Call $O(x)$ the orbit of $x$. It has period $T$.

Suppose $F(x_n,t)$ converges to $F(x,t)$ uniformly on $t$.
(Building a counterexample in $\mathbb R^2$ looks difficult, because the $O(x_n)$ cannot cross each other, so it rules out the usual counterexample to "pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence").

Then as $n \to \infty$, it should be possible to prove that $p_F(x_n)$ modulo $T$ $\to 0$, due to continuity of $F$.

As $O(x)$ is continuous and cannot cross itself, it is a Jordan curve, a closed loop.
Due to uniform convergence of $O(x_n)$ to $O(x)$, and the fact that $p_F(x_n)[T]\to 0$, we should be able to prove that $\exists n, O(x_n)$ makes at least $2$ loops around $O(x)$ (if it is exterior to $O(x)$), or around some point inside $O(x)$ (if it is interior to $O(x)$).
But in $\mathbb R^2$ it is impossible for a continuous curve to make $2$ or more loops around something without self-intersecting.

Note that this continuity of $p_F$ would hold in $\mathbb R^2$, but not in $\mathbb R^d$ for $d>2$: in $\mathbb R^3$ it is possible for $O(x_n)$ to follow $O(x)$ closely and make $p \ge 2$ loops while not self-intersecting.